# Concatenating (many) CSV files via Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, concatenation

I am basically trying to concatenate many csv files of time series type in Pandas I was certain I knew how to do it but apparently I don't.

Consider this simple example:

We have three csv files:

file1.csv=

```
Alfa, A1, A2, A3, A4
Beta, B1, B2, B3, B4
Gamma, C1, C2, C3, C4
```

file2.csv=

```
Delta, D1, D2, D3, D4
Epsilon, E1, E2, E3, E4
Zeta, F1, F2, F3, F4
```

file3.csv=

```
Eta, G1, G2, G3, G4
Theta, H1, H2, H3, H4
Iota, I1, I2, I3, I4
```

**1st toy code**:

```
[In]:

import pandas as pd
a = pd.read_csv("/Test/file1.csv", header=None)
b = pd.read_csv("/Test/file2.csv", header=None)
c = pd.read_csv("/Test/file3.csv", header=None)
colnames = ["GREEK", "ROW1", "ROW2", "ROW3", "ROW4"]
concatDf = pd.concat([a,b,c], axis=0)
concatDf.columns = colnames
print(concatDf)

[Out]:

     GREEK ROW1 ROW2 ROW3 ROW4
0     Alfa   A1   A2   A3   A4
1     Beta   B1   B2   B3   B4
2    Gamma   C1   C2   C3   C4
0    Delta   D1   D2   D3   D4
1  Epsilon   E1   E2   E3   E4
2     Zeta   F1   F2   F3   F4
0      Eta   G1   G2   G3   G4
1    Theta   H1   H2   H3   H4
2     Iota   I1   I2   I3   I4
```

Not pretty, but does what it is suppose to do.
Since the names of the real CSV-file are very long and the number of files are high, I thought I should make things a bit easier for me. Hence **2nd toy code**:

```
[In]:

import glob
import pandas as pd

 allFiles = glob.glob("/Test/" + "*.csv")
 dfList = []
 for filename in allaFiler:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    dfList.append(df)

 concatDf = pd.concat(dfList, axis=0)
 print(concatDf)

[Out]:

    A1  A2  A3  A4  D1  D2  D3  D4  G1  G2  G3  G4 Alfa   Delta   Eta
0   B1  B2  B3  B4 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN Beta     NaN   NaN   
1   C1  C2  C3  C4 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN Gamma    NaN   NaN   
0  NaN NaN NaN NaN  E1  E2  E3  E4 NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN Epsilon   NaN   
1  NaN NaN NaN NaN  F1  F2  F3  F4 NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN    Zeta   NaN   
0  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  H1  H2  H3  H4  NaN     NaN Theta  
1  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  I1  I2  I3  I4  NaN     NaN  Iota
```

file1.csv, file2.csv, and file3.csv are the only files in the Test map.
I have checked the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html), but I have failed to find an explanation.

My questions are as follows:

1. Why doesn't code 2 yield the same result as code 1? I am clearly missing something very fundamental, so please help me to understand what is going on.
2. What changes do I have to do to make code 2 yield the same result as code 1?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The basic issue is that each of your CSVs have different row names, so the indices do not align during concatenation. The quickest fix is to rename your dataframe columns (`list('ABCD')`) before you append to `dfList`.

Comment: So basically all I have to do is to name the rows in a uniform way?

Comment: yes, and I've written an answer that shows you how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears all your dataframes have different names. This causes `pd.concat` to misalign the dataframes during concatenation.

The solution would be to name each one consistently before concatenation. Use the `names` parameter to specify the column name when reading your dataframes.

```
dfList = []
for filename in allaFiler:
   df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None, names=list('ABCD'))
   dfList.append(df)
```

Comment: Thank you VERY MUCH! Worked like a charm!!

Comment: I think skiprows=0 or the alpha row wont be included.

Comment: @userjuicer I inferred this based on what was written in your question. If you feel any changes were needed, feel free to edit my post and I'll accept your edit.

Comment: Again thanks, you have no idea how much time you have saved me!

Comment: @userjuicer No problem. Actually, if skiprows=0, you can just omit the argument completely. Happy coding.